# Symfony countries by locale

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

I would like to extend Symfony's Country Form Type, so that it automatically sets as preferred choices all countries corresponding to the current locale. For example if locale is set to 'en' I would like the preferred choices to include all english speaking countries (US, JM..) , while if locale is 'en_JM' I would like to just add JM to the preferred choices.

I know how to get the locale inside a form, but I was wondering, is there a preferred way to extract this list of country codes by short locale (ie: en or de )using Symfony i18n components?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to get all the countries that speak that language, but you can create an array of ISO alpha-2 country codes for each language and then pass in the locale to a custom form type as one of the required options.

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $builder->add('location', new LocationType(), array(
        'locale' => $request->getLocale(),
    ));
}
```

Custom form type

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $preferredChoices = array(
            'en' => array(
                'US', // United States
                'CA', // Canada
                'GB', // United Kingdom
                'IE', // Ireland
                'AU', // Australia
                'ZA', // South Africa
                // etc
            ),
            'it' => array(
                'IT', // Italy
                'CH', // Switzerland
            ),
            'nl' => array(
                'NL', // Netherlands
                'BE', // Belgium
                'SR', // Suriname
                'ZA', // South Africa
            ),
        );

        $builder
            ->add('country', 'country', array(
                'preferred_choices' => $preferredChoices[$options['locale']],
            ))
            // ->add( more )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'locale',
        ));
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes(array(
            'locale' => 'string',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'location';
    }
}
```

Comment: yes thx that makes sense, but I was looking for a way to get that array from the built in i18n system without having to write it myself... One option is maybe to get a list of all full locales in the format [a-z]_[AZ] and then extract all that start with my short locale... but I was wondering if there was a better way...

Comment: One option is to use 

    $variants = \Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getLocaleBundle()->getLocaleNames();

and then filtering it by selecting only the elements that start with the language code.

Still its a big array so this might be inefficient, it would be better to create a cache of each subarray.